# Unit test a method to return the expected value

Tags: angular, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I wanted to unit test a service file.

In the service I've two functions, `getInlineView` & `breakByRanges`.

**INPUT**

```
const data = {
    "text": "Do you have questions or comments and do you wish to contact ABC? Please visit our customer support page.",
    "inlineStyleRanges": [],
    "inlineEntityRanges": [{
        "type": "LINK",
        "offset": 83,
        "length": 16,
        "data": {
            "target": "_self",
            "url": "/index.htm"
        }
    }]
}
```

SO If I pass the above `INPUT` to `breakData, I get the below`OUTPUT`

**OUTPUT**

```
[{"data":"Do you have questions or comments and do you wish to contact ABC? Please visit our ","type":"text"},{"data":"customer support ","type":"LINK"},{"data":"page.","type":"text"}]
```

Below is my Spec,

```
describe('GenerateInlineTagsService', () => {
  let service: GenerateInlineTagsService;
  beforeEach(() => TestBed.configureTestingModule({}));

  it('should call getInlineView method ', () => {
    const spy = spyOn<any>(service, 'getInlineView').and.returnValue(ENTITY_RANGERS);
    service.getInlineView(data);
    const obj2 = JSON.stringify(ENTITY_RANGERS); // refers to output mock
    expect(JSON.stringify(spy)).toEqual(obj2);
  });
});
```

**So the Problem ?**

I passing the `data` as input to to `getInlineView`, and expecting the return value is equal to the mock value `ENTITY_RANGERS` (OUTPUT).

But I'm getting the below error

> Expected undefined to equal '[{"data":"Do you have questions or
>   comments and do you wish to contact ABC? Please visit our
>   ","type":"text"},{"data":"customer support
>   ","type":"LINK"},{"data":"page.","type":"text"}]'.

Please help.

Below is the link to the actual function,

https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-qxndgd

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to compare the spy that you set up on your service function, to the actual expected result, which obviously doesn't work.

Change your code to something along the lines of:

```
it('should call getInlineView method ', () => {
  const spy = spyOn(service, 'getInlineView').and.returnValue(ENTITY_RANGERS);
  expect(spy).not.toHaveBeenCalled();

  // this will get you the mock value you provided in your spy above, as all calls to this function will now be handled by the spy
  const result = service.getInlineView(data);
  expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);

  const obj2 = JSON.stringify(ENTITY_RANGERS); // refers to output mock
  expect(JSON.stringify(result)).toEqual(obj2);
});
```